# Are Errors still present in JSF Mojarra 2.2.5 with flash scope?

Tags: jsf-2.2, flash-scope

Still getting this error with last Mojarra 2.2.5 version when i tried to get back my flash parameters.

`29 janv. 2014 08:24:22 com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash getCurrentFlashManager`
`GRAVE: JSF1094: Could not decode flash data from incoming cookie value Invalid characters   in decrypted value.  Processing will continue, but the flash is unavailable for this request.`

I was thinking the bug was closed with 2.2.5 .... ? Is there another configuration to make or Mojarra flash implementation of the `busted Intern` is still harmful ? :)

Thanks.

I' m using :

- RichFaces 4.3.4.Final
- Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
- Spring 3.2.2 (with Spring security)

Comment: +1 solely for "busted Intern" ;-) And yes, I still see this with Mojarra-2.2.5

Comment: BalusC (who is no more an intern :) write :"the last open problem of Flash scope not being available after a redirect on a different path is solved in the shortly upcoming Mojarra 2.1.14. So with this version, all Flash scope related problems discovered and open so far should be solved and closed. :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148798/object-in-flash-scope-is-not-available-after-redirect?rq=1" maybe i misunderstood

Comment: JSF Flash scope is evil. Pfff...

Comment: *"discovered and open so far"* ... Flash problems keep accumulating :( You can find a more recent overview here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21230965. Haven't tried Flash in 2.2.5 myself yet.

Comment: Hummm So is there another way to pass parameters not displayed in the URL using the Post-Redirect-Get implementation from Pretty Faces ?

Comment: I'm was still seeing this message for 2.2.14 and upgrading to 2.2.15 did not help.

I don't really use Flash but "SEVERE" log statements annoy me. ;)