# Logout message doesn't show

Tags: jsf, session, redirect, message

When I logout from my application it doesn't show my logout message

**I have an outputText trying to show the message in my view (`<h:outputText id="message" value="#{loginMB.message}" />`):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <o:form id="login" includeViewParams="true">
            <h:outputText id="message" value="#{loginMB.message}" />
            ... Another components ...
        </o:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

**And this is my backing bean:**

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserBB implements Serializable {

    private String message;

    public void logout() {
        try {
            message = "You have been logout successfully";

            SecurityUtils.getSubject().logout();
            Faces.invalidateSession();
            Faces.redirect("login.xhtml");
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            ... Another code ...
        }
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Why it doesn't show my logout message?

**Edit:**

**Logout method:**

```
public void logout() {
    SecurityUtils.getSubject().logout();
    Messages.addFlashGlobalInfo("You have successfully log out");
    Faces.invalidateSession();
    Faces.redirect("login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&lo=t");
}
```

**logout button:**

```
<p:commandButton action="#{userBB.logout}" value="log out" />
```

Comment: scope of you managed bean???

Comment: Session scope. I just edited my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Why it doesn't show my logout message?*

Because you've assigned it as a property of a session scoped bean and are then invalidating the session and sending a redirect. The invalidation of the session will destroy the session scope and all objects stored in it, including session scoped managed beans. The redirect thereafter will create a brand new request and session and all session scoped managed beans will be newly recreated, with all properties set to default.

There are 2 problems with this approach:

1. Using `<h:outputText>` instead of `<h:message(s)>` to display the message(s).
2. Storing the message in the session scope instead of the [flash scope](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/flash-scope/info).

To solve your problem, use `<h:message(s)>` to display the message(s) and use `FacesContext#addMessage()` or, as you're already using OmniFaces, its [`Messages`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Messages) utility class, to add a message to the faces context. You can use `<h:messages globalOnly="true">` to display only global messages (i.e. those with a `null` client ID). You can use [`Flash#setKeepMessages()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/Flash.html#setKeepMessages%28boolean%29) to tell JSF to store all messages of the current request in the flash scope instead.

Thus, all in all, this should do:

```
<h:messages id="messages" globalOnly="true" />
```

with

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped // Doesn't need to be session scoped for the particular task.
public class UserManager {

    public void logout() throws Exception {
        SecurityUtils.getSubject().logout();
        Messages.addFlashGlobalInfo("You have been logged out successfully");
        Faces.invalidateSession();
        Faces.redirect("login.xhtml");
    }

}
```

For the interested, here's how it would look like using "plain JSF":

```
    public void logout() throws Exception {
        SecurityUtils.getSubject().logout();
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("You have been logged out successfully"));
        ExternalContext externalContext = context.getExternalContext();
        externalContext.getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
        externalContext.invalidateSession();
        externalContext.redirect("login.xhtml");
    }
```

Important note is that the [flash scope is severly broken in older Mojarra versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168059/jsf-messages-persistance/21230965#21230965). You need a minimum of 2.1.27 to get rid of all those problems.

Comment: I will make these changes today. Thanks

Comment: Excuse me @BalusC. With this solution I have had the following problem: When I need to log in after my session is closed automatically, the logout message appears the next time I log in

Comment: How exactly are you performing the logout? Via a command button/link, right? And which JSF impl/version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

```
Faces.invalidateSession();
```

This will `destroy` the `session` and since the bean is session scoped all the data will be lost.

**Solution:**

```
 Faces.redirect("login.xhtml?msg=You have been logged out sucessfully");
```

and in your xhtml

```
<h:outputText id="message" value="#{param['msg']}"/>
```

**If not want to show in url**

Create another file `logout.xhtml` (Actually logout.xhtml will have same code as login.xhtml just add extra line you want)

Comment: Ok. How I can fix this?

Comment: What can I do to hide the message in the url location bar?

Answer (score 1):

you can also hide the mesage with url paramter.

```java
Faces.redirect("login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&logoutMsg=true");
```

and xhtml

```xhtml
<h:outputText value="You have been logged out sucessfully" 
rendered="#{not empty param['logoutMsg']}"/>
```