# After post is setting a value in JSF2 flash scope, it is visible again on second GET request to a page (Flash scope considered harmful)

Tags: jsf-2, mojarra, flash-scope

I tested new Flash scope in JSF2 but I found a major issue with it or I am lacking some knowledge.

Having a page:

```
<h:body>
    Value in flash: #{flash.text}
    <h:form>    
         <h:inputText value="#{flash.text}" />
         <h:commandButton value="Test" /> <!-- Same behavior with faces redirect -->
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

I have a scenario:

- Put a value 'foo' and click Test
- I get 'Value in flash: foo'
- I open new page with the same adress
- I get 'Value in flash:'
- I open another new page with the same adress
- I get 'Value in flash: **foo**' <- IMHO this is wrong!

Reproducibility: 100%
Tested on Glassfish 3.1 and JBoss AS 7

Different problem with probably same reason: [Removing JSF messages from the flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343147/removing-jsf-messages-from-the-flash)

So:

- Is it desired behavior of JSF2 flash?
- Based on this and other noticed problems with flash, shoud the reference flash implementation be considered harmful?

Comment: Workaround: Usually when one would like to use Flash, one should use e.g. Seam 3 [RenderScope](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/faces/latest/reference/en-US/html/scopes.html#RenderScoped)

Comment: It is not the case with Jetty8 I have tried in it.

Answer (score 2):

I think for now the implementation of The Flash should be considered harmful indeed. In the application I'm working on day to day I had a very good use case for it, but unfortunately The Flash just appeared to be unusable.

The main problem is that the cookie which is used to transfer a pointer to the state isn't cleared, see [Flash scoped message lives longer than next request](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1751).

There also seems to be a security problem with the flash scope, see [Flash scope cookie enables data exploits](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2126).

*If any of this bothers you, please vote for the linked issues ;)*

Comment: Thanks. Does [RenderScope](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/faces/latest/reference/en-US/html/scopes.html#RenderScoped) can replace Flash in your use case?

Comment: Yes, this seems to be able to do the trick. My use case is a very classic redirect-after-post scenario, where the redirected page simply needs to display a message. An additional bonus is that there is a provision to generate an ID for any context other than the first one in case there are multiple ones active.